# How do you execute an action when a button reaches the top of a web browser screen using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to execute an action when a user scrolls and a button reaches the top of the screen. My original script works when I only use one button. But when I add multiple buttons my script doesn't work.

My original script that works is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var distance = $("button[data-page='2']").offset().top;

    $(window).on("scroll",function() {
        if (checkVisible($("button[data-page='2']"))) {
            console.log('button 2 scrolled to the top');
            $(window).off('scroll');
        }


        else {
            // do nothing
        }


    });

    function checkVisible( elm, eval ) {
        eval = eval || "object visible";
        var viewportHeight = $(window).height(), // Viewport Height
            scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop(), // Scroll Top
            y = $(elm).offset().top,
            elementHeight = $(elm).height();

        if (eval == "object visible") return ((y < (viewportHeight + scrolltop)) && (y > (scrolltop - elementHeight)));
        if (eval == "above") return ((y < (viewportHeight + scrolltop)));
    }



});
```

The HTML is

```
    <button data-page="2">
        Load More
    </button>

    <div>
        content
    </div>
```

But when I add multiple buttons my script doesn't work and I get the following error message in my console: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined**

I figure that I may need to create multiple functions? Not sure why it's not working

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var distance = $("button[data-page='2']").offset().top;

    $(window).on("scroll",function() {
        if (checkVisible($("button[data-page='2']"))) {
            console.log('button 2 scrolled to the top');
            $(window).off('scroll');
        }

        else if (checkVisible($("button[data-page='3']"))) {
            console.log('button 3 scrolled to the top');
            $(window).off('scroll');
        }

        else if (checkVisible($("button[data-page='4']"))) {
            console.log('button 4 scrolled to the top');
            $(window).off('scroll');
        }

        else {
            // do nothing
        }


    });

    function checkVisible( elm, eval ) {
        eval = eval || "object visible";
        var viewportHeight = $(window).height(), // Viewport Height
            scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop(), // Scroll Top
            y = $(elm).offset().top,
            elementHeight = $(elm).height();

        if (eval == "object visible") return ((y < (viewportHeight + scrolltop)) && (y > (scrolltop - elementHeight)));
        if (eval == "above") return ((y < (viewportHeight + scrolltop)));
    }



});
```

The HTML is:

```
    <button data-page="2">
        Load More
    </button>

    <div>
        content
    </div>

    <button data-page="3">
        Load More
    </button>

    <div>
        content
    </div>

    <button data-page="4">
        Load Mo

    <div>
        content
    </div>
```

I should mention that data-page="3" and data-page="4" may not be in the DOM and not display until button data-page="2" is clicked.

I've included an image example to display my layout
[image]

Comment: And you're sure the element is in the DOM? Is it happening for specific `data-page-x` element? And BTW, you're already passing a jQuery object to  `checkVisible` so you don't need to wrap it again in jquery `$(elm)`

Comment: And you also need to make sure the elements are not `display:none;` because reading after the documentation, for invisible elements the `.offset()` function returns `undefined` (Unlike `visibility:hidden` that will work)

Comment: @AlonEitan Good questions.  `data-page="x"` where x is dynamic so the value changes when the button is clicked. For example when button with attribute `data-page="2"` is clicked it changes into  `data-page="3"`

Comment: Well in that case you must make sure they exist. Add `if( !elm.length ) { return false; }` at the very top of `checkVisible` and it should skip checking unexciting elements

Comment: @AlonEitan Thanks. When you wrote at the very top did you mean right above  `if (checkVisible($("button[data-page='2']")))...` or will I need to wrap it? Do you have an example?

Comment: @AlonEitan Thanks. When you wrote at the very top did you mean right above  `function checkVisible..` or will I need to wrap it? Do you have an example?

Comment: I mean - The first line of the function:`function checkVisible( elm, eval ) { if( !elm.length ) { return false; } /* REST OF THE CODE */ }`

Comment: @AlonEitan,Thanks. That worked but I would like to use multiple buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var hasRun = false
  $(window).on('scroll', scrollHandler)
})

var scrollHandler = function() {
  if (hasReachedTop('button[data-page="2"]')) {
    console.error('button 2 has reached the top')
    $(window).off('scroll', scrollHandler)
  }
}

var hasReachedTop = function (selector) {
  return $(document).scrollTop() >= $(selector).offset().top
}
```

Edited the code to remove the `scroll` listener if the button hits the top.

Comment: There are also many useful libraries to see where things are when they are 'in view' https://camwiegert.github.io/in-view/

Comment: @Radu Dascălu This is good but it runs multiple times when I scroll. I only would like for it to run once

Comment: @Mariton Please let me know if my changes of the code are what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @RaduDascălu Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of loading content dynamically upon scroll via AJAX. You can put a a button to load content manually too. but the example is without a button at the end.

**JQuery Example:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(window).scroll(function(){

  var position = $(window).scrollTop();
  var bottom = $(document).height() - $(window).height();

  if( position == bottom ){

   var row = Number($('#row').val());
   var allcount = Number($('#all').val());
   var rowperpage = 3;
   row = row + rowperpage;

   if(row <= allcount){
    $('#row').val(row);
    $.ajax({
     url: 'fetch_details.php',
     type: 'post',
     data: {row:row},
     success: function(response){
      $(".post:last").after(response).show().fadeIn("slow");
     }
    });
   }
  }

 });

});
```

**Complete Code and example demo available on page:**[Load content on page scroll with jQuery and AJAX](http://makitweb.com/load-content-on-page-scroll-with-jquery-and-ajax/). See the demo at the end of the page and see the JQuery part and solve your problem on your own.

Comment: Well since I'm not using an AJAX call and just displaying content  I figured that I would  display content once each button reaches the top. So it would be similar to adding  `var datstuff = $('button[data-page]').attr('data-page');` and do something similar to `if(datstuff == 3) {// Do something}` It's not working for me